# change based on user select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I am trying to do is have 2 sets of questions and have them change based on my first question.

If you are an owner I have a different set of questions then if you are not a owner. I can do this but in a really bad way it seems to me... with replacewith...should I have a div a make it invisible and make it come in if it's the selected one?  If I have to do it the way I am now I would like to have the answer box first if I can instead of at the end of the text? Thanks in advance! I have included a fiddle

```
<select>
      <option value=>owner</option>
      <option value=>non-owner</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/philyphil/LjxGB/embedded/result/

Comment: Heh, `shift` key broken?

Comment: lol no it works. I have a 1 track mind and it's on making this work. If i thought capitalization would have helped me get a answer, I gladly would have lol

Comment: You *are* more likely to get a good answer if the question is easy to read, well formatted, etc =D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attach a 'change' function to the select box, check the value of the selected option in that function and use the value to select and display the correct set of questions.

(updated to actually work this time) Click it -> [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/relic180/j5cdK/)

```
<select class="myOptions">
  <option data-val="" selected>Pick an option</option>
  <option data-val="owner">Owner</option>
  <option data-val="not-owner">Not Owner</option>
</select>

<div class="list owner">
    <p>abc</p>
  <!-- questions for owners -->
</div>

<div class="list not-owner">
    <p>xyz</p>
  <!-- questions for non-owners -->
</div>
```

little bit of css...

```
.list { display:none; }
.list.active { display:block }
```

and the js...

```
$('.myOptions').change(function(){
  $('.list').removeClass('active')
  .filter('.' + $('.myOptions').children('option:selected').attr('data-val'))
  .addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Haha i had almost exactly the same answer!

Comment: +1 nice answer... the only thing I would say is that HTML spec frowns upon adding custom data attributes that are handled by regular html attributes - i.e. the data-val should be 'value'. Gez

Comment: @relic180 tried that maybe i im still to new to this made a fiddle but does not work.

Comment: @philly Updated my broken answer to a working answer... Sorry bout that.

Comment: @philly there's a javascript error  - Blocked a frame with origin "http://jsfiddle.net" from accessing a frame with origin "http://fiddle.jshell.net". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Answer (score 0):

------**EDIT**------

Please see fiddle for working code: http://jsfiddle.net/q7qGs/embedded/result/

------**//EDIT**------

Its a good idea to give your select an id and/or name attribute, with which you can easily target the field's selected option value value or text in a **onchange** or **onclick** function (callback) either in raw javascript or jquery. You could wrap each element or groups of elements in divs in the same way too.

Personally, I would use jQuery to do this since its quicker to write and pretty well cross-browser compatible but, I digress...

Essentially, in jQuery, if you have an select field defined like:

```
<select id="is_owner">
     <option value="yes">owner</option>
     <option value="no">non-owner</option>
</select>
```

you could detect a change in it's value by adding something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        $('#is_owner').change(function(){
             //set var = to the field's current value
             var value = $(this).val();

             // Check value to see which field to show/hide
             if(value == 'yes'){
                  // Show other field
                  /* YOUR CODE TO SHOW OTHER FIELD GOES HERE... target the field you want to show or hide for the yes condition as before and append .show() or .hide() respecively*/
             }
             else if(value == 'no'){
                  // Show other field
                  /* YOUR CODE TO SHOW OTHER FIELD GOES HERE... (see above*/
             }
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

For more information about jQuery and how to use it please see [jQuery Website](http://jquery.com/) in addition to a [forum post/tutorial](http://www.j-cook.net/index.php/forum/jquery/4481-show-hide-fields-in-front-end-form?limitstart=0&start=15#4484) on conditionally displaying/hiding form elements based on the value of another.

Hope it helps,

Gez

Comment: Not my day... i'm sure it's just me..but can't get it to work    http://jsfiddle.net/philyphil/LjxGB/2/embedded/result/

Comment: @ relic180 np thank you very much i appreciate it very much! Thank you to everyone else as well you guys are always the best!!!